# how add python class to a xml parsing program

Tags: python

I have a program that will take input xml and print same xml as output. How can i implement class and method for that ?

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import sys   
doc       = ET.parse("users.xml")
root      = doc.getroot()
root_new  = ET.Element("users") 
for child in root:
    username             = child.attrib['username']
    password             = child.attrib['password']   
    # create "user" here
    user    = ET.SubElement(root_new, "user") 
    user.set("username",username)               
    user.set("password",password) 
    #checking attribute for skipping KeyError
    if 'remote_access' in child.attrib:
        remote_access   = child.attrib['remote_access']
        user.set("remote_access",remote_access) 
    for g in child.findall("group"):
        # create "group" here
        group     = ET.SubElement(user,"group")  
        if g.text != "lion":
            group.text = g.text 
tree = ET.ElementTree(root_new)
tree.write(sys.stdout)
```

How to convert this to class concept . Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please dont said it is a nonsense or no nedd. its highly needed :(

Comment: If it is highly needed, then you should put some more effort into your question. For instance, provide a sample of the input you have and the output you expect. It also helps if you describe what you have tried and where exactly you are stuck. The more specific your question is the more likely you are to get an answer. Note that SO does not look kindly on question of the *give me teh codez*-type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, there are probably thousands of ways to do it.
You want an example, here it is (I'm assuming your code is working):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import sys   


class MyXmlParser(object):

    def __init__(self, xml_file_name):
        self.doc  = ET.parse(xml_file_name)
        self.root = doc.getroot()

    def do_something(self, output = sys.stdout):
        root_new  = ET.Element("users") 
        for child in self.root:
            username             = child.attrib['username']
            password             = child.attrib['password']   
            # create "user" here
            user    = ET.SubElement(root_new, "user") 
            user.set("username",username)               
            user.set("password",password) 
            # checking attribute - skip KeyError
            try:
                remote_access   = child.attrib['remote_access']
                user.set("remote_access", remote_access) 
            except KeyError:
                pass

            for g in child.findall("group"):
                # create "group" here
                group     = ET.SubElement(user,"group")  
                if g.text != "lion":
                    group.text = g.text 
        tree = ET.ElementTree(root_new)
        tree.write(output)

def main():
    my_parser = MyXmlParser("users.xml")
    my_parser.do_something()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Oh my god,am looking something same,,wait i verify dude :), thanks a lot, if its working i accept it.